# php foreach select item

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
    $directory = "img/media/";
    $files = glob($directory. '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

//Loop through images
foreach($files as $image)
{
    echo'
        <div class="card animation_one p-0 m-0">
            <img class="card-img" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-center bg-offBlue t-pureWhite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="">Bekijk</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
?>
```

My question is for some people very simple but i just started with coding so i need some help on this. If i have a foreach loop how do i know and display the selected (in this case img) to show in the modal popup?

Comment: you should use javascript (jquery suggested) to detect last user's selection and do something with that object. I think i could not understand what do you want

Comment: This is **not** a php question. it's a html / css question. You have to print the right html markup for a modal popup window... php is processed on the server but "popups" appear at the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this brother,

with help of foreach

```
//Loop through images
$count=0;
foreach($files as $image)
{
    echo'
        <div class="card animation_one p-0 m-0">
            <img class="card-img" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-center bg-offBlue t-pureWhite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_'.$count.'" onclick="">Bekijk</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_'.$count.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
    $count+=1;
}
```

with for loop

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++)
{
    $image=$files[$i];
    echo'
        <div class="card animation_one p-0 m-0">
            <img class="card-img" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-center bg-offBlue t-pureWhite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_'.$i.'" onclick="">Bekijk</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_'.$i.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="'. $image .'" alt="Card image">
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
}
```